# cast to pointer from integer of different size -wint-to-pointer-cast

Tags: c, semaphore

Hello i have the next problem in my code:

> "cast to pointer from integer of different size -wint-to-pointer-cast"

This problem is in this line of code

```
pthread_create(&filos[i], NULL, (void *)filosofos,(void *) i);
```

Specifically in **(void *) i**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5               //num. de filosofos
#define IZQ (i-1)%N      //vecino izquierdo de i
#define DER (i+1)%N      //vecino derecho de i
#define PENSANDO 0
#define CON_HAMBRE 1
#define COME 2


pthread_t filos[N];       //hilos que representan a los filósofos
sem_t mutex ;             //semáforo para la sección crítica
sem_t s[N];               //semáforos para los filósofos
int estado [N] ;          //estado actual de cada filósosfo


/* 
    el filosofo i va a perder el tiempo... (va a pensar)
 */
void pensar (int i) 
{
  int t ;
  t = rand() % 11;
  printf("Filosofo %d pensando \n", i) ;
  estado[i] = PENSANDO;
  sleep (t) ;
}


/* 
    El filosofo i, va a comer !!!!!!!!
 */
void comer (int i) 
{
  printf("Filósofo %d esta comiendo un caballo \n", i);
  estado[i] = COME;
  sleep (5);
}


/* 
    Verifica que pueda tomar ambos tenedores
*/
void verifica(int i) 
{
  if( estado[i]==CON_HAMBRE && estado[IZQ]!=COME && estado[DER]!=COME ){
    estado[i] = COME;
    printf("Filósofo %d comiendo\n", i) ;
    sem_post(&s[i]);
  }
}


/* 
    El filosofo i intenta tomar los  tenedores
 */
void toma_tndrs(int i)
{

  sem_wait(&mutex);             //entra a la sección crítica, hace uso del semaforo
  estado[i] = CON_HAMBRE;      //dice: tengo mucha hambre!!!!!!!!!!
  verifica(i);                 // verifica que pueda tomar los tenedores
  sem_post(&mutex);            //sale de la sección crítica y el sem. puede permitir la entrada a alguien más
  sem_wait(&s[i]);            //se bloquea si no consiguió los tenedores
}


/* 
    el filosofo i dejará los tenedores
 */
void deja_tndrs(int i)
{

  sem_wait(&mutex);       // de nuevo entra a la sección critica
  estado[i] = PENSANDO;  //deja de comer y se pone a pensar
  verifica(IZQ);        
  verifica(DER);
  sem_post(&mutex);
}


/* 


 */
void * filosofos (int i)
{
  int j ;


  for (; ; )
    {
      pensar(i) ;
      toma_tndrs(i) ;
      comer(i) ;
      deja_tndrs(i) ;
    }
}


main()
{
  int i ;


  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    sem_init (&s[i], 0, 1);


    estado[i] = PENSANDO ;
  }


  sem_init (&mutex, 0, 1);

  //creamos un hilo de ejecucion para cada filosofo, que ejecuta filosofos()
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    pthread_create(&filos[i], NULL, (void *)filosofos,(void *) i);

  //cada hilo espera a que terminen los demás y libera los recursos
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    pthread_join(filos[i],NULL);
  }

}
```

Comment: `int` might be a different size than a `void*`, and that cast might be unsafe if the pointer is ever referenced. You should either pass  a pointer to the `int` value, casting that. Or use `intptr_t`.

Comment: You should not try to do threading before understand basic C.

Comment: @Evert *You're casting the integer i to a pointer to void: `(void *) i`. You should be casting the pointer to i: `(void *)&i`*  No.  Passing the address of `i` to a child thread creates a race condition - the value of `i` is likely to change by the time the child thread accesses it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ah, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming it's the cast of the `i` variable that causes the problem, first cast it to an integer type that is larger than `int` and at the same time large enough to hold a pointer.

One such type, designed for the very purpose of being large enough to hold any integer or pointer, is `intptr_t`, described in e.g. [this fixed-width integer reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

The cast would then look like

```
(void *) (intptr_t) i
```

In the thread function you do the opposite, *first* cast to `intptr_t` and then to `int`.

```
void * filosofos (void *p)
{
    int i = (int) (intptr_t) p;

    ...

    return NULL;
}
```

Note that I changed the signature of the thread function to be correct, it takes a `void *` argument, and this makes a whole lot difference on systems where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void *)`, which seems to be true in your case. Also note that I return a `NULL` at the end of the function. That's because the thread function is declared (and specified) to return a pointer. Not returning a value from a function declared to do so leads to *undefined behavior*.

---

For those curious, while I would normally not recommend casting an integer to a pointer like this, there are exceptions to everything and this is one of the few cases (if not the only one) where such a cast is acceptable.

Many still look down on such a solution, but still use it since it's easier than the whole `malloc`-copy-`free` circus that's otherwise needed.

A solution using dynamic allocated memory for the value would look something like this:

- Thread creation

  ```
  // Allocate memory for the index
  int *p = malloc(sizeof i);
  if (p == NULL)
  {
      // TOOD: Handle error! (Left as an exercise to the reader)
  }

  // Copy the value
  *p = i;

  // And create the thread
  pthread_create(&filos[i], NULL, &filosofos, p);  // Note: no cast needed
  ```
- In the thread function

  ```
  void * filosofos (void *p)
  {
      int i = *(int *) p;
      free(p);

      ...

      return NULL;
  }
  ```

While this solution is more "correct", it is less readable which means it's less maintainable; It has more code which means more chances of errors; And it has the possibility of a memory leak if the `free` call is forgotten (which sooner or later *will* happen).

Comment: I don't think is a good idea to show this. The good way would be to send a true pointer. Maybe would be better to create an array of integer to show a better way. By the way, `int estado [N];` The OP already have one to do this.

Comment: @Stargateur The purpose is to pass an index into the `estado` array to the thread. Using another array doesn't make much sense as then the thread would need an index into *that* array.

Comment: I completely agree with Some programmer dude. This scheme is very commonly used with thread pool workers. I personally prefer to make the conversion explicit and easy to verify by using macros (in the hopes that learners notice the issue); in this case, perhaps `#define INT_TO_PTR(i) ((void *)(intptr_t)(i))` and `#define PTR_TO_INT(ptr) ((int)(intptr_t)(ptr))`. (And, for similar reasons, maybe `const int i = PTR_TO_INT(p);` in the example.)

Comment: *While this solution is more "correct", it is less readable which means it's less maintainable* Not only that, the `malloc()`/`free()` solution might very well be a performance bottleneck as it effectively single-threads all the newly-started children through the heap.  It also impacts new thread creation performance because the child `free()` calls impede the parent's `malloc()` calls. More less-maintainable, bug-prone, slower code isn't what I'd call a "good way" of doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting `i` to a void pointer without creating a reference to it. I'm not a spanish speaker, but I can assume you meant to do:

```
pthread_create(&filos[i], NULL, (void *)filosofos, (void *)&i);
```

Otherwise, you've created a reference to memory address `i`, and there's nothing you can touch in memory with such a low address :P

Also, casting explicitly to and from void pointers is a something to avoid.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Try learning a bit more about pointers.

Comment: The problem with passing a pointer to `i` (for which no cast is needed) is that then all threads would share the same pointer, and even if they copy the value it will lead to a data-race.